# Insert string to foreach result

Tags: php, function, insert, foreach, ads

I have a view forum post script

```
if(isset($replys)){
    foreach ($replys as $reply) {
        echo $reply['name'].' | '.$reply['date'];
    }
}
```

output like:

```
abc | 2013-1-1
123 | 2013-1-2
456 | 2013-1-3
```

then I want to randomly display ads
for example:

```
abc | 2013-1-1
Google Ads | testing
123 | 2013-1-2
456 | 2013-1-3
```

using some if statement:

```
if( is_string(substr(sha1(uniqid()),-1)) ){
// show ads
}
```

how can I do this?

Comment: if( is_string(substr(sha1(uniqid()),-1)) ){
// show ads
} will this generate random string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find a random spot to insert the ad:

```
if (is_string(substr(sha1(uniqid()),-1))) {
    // show ads
    $offset = mt_rand(0, count($replys) - 1);
    $ad = array('name' => 'Google Ads', 'date' => 'testing');

    $replys = array_splice($replys, $offset, 0, $ad);
}
```

Comment: can I insert ads to random position in replies?